# How to flatten results of a SQLAlchemy query in one single object?

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy

I have a `User` model and I want to make a query to get all the users with some extra  calculated fields. I'm using SQLAlchemy to perform my query and Flask for templating:

```
db.session.query(User, func.sum(Pet).label(nb_pets).join(Pet.parent_id === User.id)
```

The result I get has this format:

```
[(<User 123>, 4), (<User 456>, 1), ...]
```

If I want to render the list of users in my template I'll have to do

```
{% for row in users %}
   {{ row[0].name }}
   {{ row.nb_pets }}
{% endfor %}
```

What should I do to add the calculated fields on the user object? I'd like to be able to perform:

```
{% for user in users %}
   {{ user.name }}
   {{ user.nb_pets }}
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [sequence unpacking](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#tuples-and-sequences) to split the "row" into its two parts:

```
{% for user, nb_pets in users %}
   {{ user.name }}
   {{ nb_pets }}
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just select the attributes of the `User` model you want.

```
db.session.query(User.name, func.sum(Pet).label(nb_pets).join(Pet.parent_id === User.id).all()
```